# Securing privacy of "who communicates with whom" under Orwell-like conditions

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, computer-science, cryptography

Assume that there is a big and powerful country with an
information-greedy secret service which has backdoors to all internet nodes 
throughout the world which permit him to observe all exchanged data and all
computations done inside the nodes.

Is it still possible under these conditions to ensure by mathematical means
that this secret service cannot find out who communicates with whom,
if one designs internet protocols in a suitable way?

My feeling is that the answer is likely "yes", but I am not working in cryptography.
-- Probably a cryptographer can tell more.

**Clarification (added after the first two answers):** 
A good answer to this question could either consist of a description of
a method together with substantial heuristic arguments in support of its
suitability for the given purpose, or it could give substantial heuristic
arguments that there is no such method. Mere handwaving arguments in
favor of a positive or a negative answer do not answer the question.

On the other hand, the question is only meant to ask whether there are
mathematical methods which *in practice* serve the purpose,
just like *in practice* RSA can be used as a public key cryptosystem.
It is not asking for a proof or disproof (of what precisely??), since this
would not make sense.

**Added after the first 5 answers (excluding deleted one(s)):** 
The answers given so far mostly take the question as a soft question,
which it is not. So far, Goldstern's answer comes closest to answering
the question in that it proposes a concrete method -- but as it stands,
it is still quite a way to go to get to anything practical.

Let me also emphasize that *any* transmission of data is "communication",
including transmissions of publicly available webpages, downloads etc..
So firstly everybody has *a lot* of communication partners, and
secondly efficiency is a very important concern.

Comment: Who would think such a horrible prospect could happen? Oh my, fortunately the real world is a much better place…

Comment: It doesn't happen very often that mathematics and the actual (political) reality are intertwined that much.

Comment: Dear MO users: please let's try not to veer off-topic. While the question might be irresistibly inviting to making coded references to the NSA controversy, I enjoin everyone to try to address the question in strict mathematical terms -- else this might have to be deleted.

Comment: I wish I could upvote Todd's comment about 6000 times.

Comment: I suggest not restricting answers to classical communication. What happens if we allow quantum protocols where all pairs of communicators have previously arranged to share a large number of EPR particle pairs. Can you do any better than in the classical case? (I suspect not, because of various no-signalling theorems, but it's not completely obvious to me.)

Comment: Use the Postal Service.  Gerhard "Check On Locked Box Problems" Paseman, 2013.10.29

Comment: @DanPiponi: Agreed, as soon as you can buy quantum computers in the next shop.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Sender's and recipient's addresses can (and are often in practice) be scanned, and the mailbox where the sender has put the letter is known as well.

Comment: That's right Stefan.  Do they scan the contents of the package too? Gerhard "Really, Check Comp. Sci. Literature" Paseman, 2013.10.29

Comment: @StefanKohl You don't need the full generality of quantum computers to implement quantum crypto. You can do non-trivial quantum crypto now, though not yet with off the shelf parts.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, the question's asking about keeping "who's communicating with whom" private. If a package was being delivered by post, then finding out who sent and received it would not be difficult, unless you have some sort of routing protocol for post in mind (which, it seems to me, reduces the postal privacy problem to the online version). Also, post is quite a lot slower than the Internet, and not suitable for many purposes. Or have I misinterpreted your comments?

Comment: There are so called privacy frameworks. Have a look at pufferfish: http://www.cse.psu.edu/~dkifer/papers/pufferfish_preprint.pdf

It's not exactly what you're looking for but it has a strong mathematical background for securing users privacy.

Comment: @Robin, I would say you have taken the wrong meaning.  There is a puzzle about sending information through insecure postal channels using lockboxes.  The mechanism could be used to send packages within packages, and mimic a number of solutions suggested in the answers below.  One answer I liked (and seems to have been deleted) could be implemented as Alice mailing a picture to a local newspaper, and that the picture is reproduced well enough that Bob can find the message in the reproduction.  Gerhard "Never Uses FedEx For Security" Paseman, 2013.10.30

Answer (score 17):

Let us assume that everybody uses the same asymmetric encryption system (such as PGP), with keys that are so large that Big Brother cannot crack them.

If Alice wants to send a message to Bob, she encrypts it with Bob's public key and broadcasts it to everybody. All of Alice's friends will use their own private keys to decrypt the message, but only Bob will succeed.  Big brother has no way of knowing who was able to read the message.  (Unless Big Brother can look over Bob's shoulder, in which case nothing will work.)

Of course this system is a bit expensive, but only by some more or less constant factor.   If everybody has 1000 friends, and sends a message per day to each of them, then I have to decode 1 million messages per day, only 1000 of which are for me.

EDIT: Now that the questions explicitly asks for a "practical" solution, here is a (slight?) improvement(?). Alice's messages will be pairs (x,y), where x looks like a large random number and y is the actual encrypted message. Whenever Alice writes to Bob, she could add a P.S. "My next message to you will be labeled with $\langle$_large random number here_$\rangle$. But please continue downloading all my messages, lest Big Brother could gain information about my conversation partners."

Comment: This scheme could also provide some sender privacy by broadcasting messages encrypted for a (securely) randomly generated key at random intervals so that Big Brother doesn't know when you actually intend to send a message.

Comment: Thank you! -- I think of the 5 answers given so far, this is the best.

Comment: And one can pad the mailing list by consistently spamming a few hundred people one doesn't know. However, if the spying-filter is at the other end, they'll know when you email the known bad-guy email-box. Unless there is powerful precedent that people do spam bad-guy mailboxes as well as everything else, catching things at a conspicuous recipient's end would still be revealing.

Comment: If the system is not applied widely but only by some people, the government can be interested in knowing the group of “common friends” listed as receivers by many senders in this broadcasting scheme. It’d give a clue that they form a group which is very much interested in protecting their privacy. This could signal that they are potentially bad guys. (see Henry Cohn's meta-questions)

Comment: I think that for a sender privacy broadcasting dummy messages is necessary. Without a sender privacy, it can be much easier to infer e.g. who is the boss in the group sending orders down through the hierarchy. It makes the system more expensive: if e.g. I want to send just one true message to someone I have to broadcast $n$ messages with $n-1$ being dummy ones. Moreover, if I don’t want to send any true message I should also broadcast $n$ messages in order to protect sender privacy of the others in the group.

Comment: And if A sends email to B but B never sends email to A, the all-knowing snoops realize that there's something fishy. And, yes, as Waldemar comments, identifying a group of 100 or 1000 emailers emailing each other en masse, possibly as a pseudo-privacy ploy, would be an obvious traffic pattern.

Comment: @paulgarrett: Would it be? I think that the flow of intended email messages is already extremely low with the weight of spam. (Which gets sent, no matter how much you flush it away or ignore it.) Would it be different in such a broadcast scheme?

Comment: If you have a small group of friends, you can certainly use this approach to maintain privacy within that group, but scaling is a problem if you want to keep the secret service from knowing who your friends are.  (If you expand the group to the size of the internet, then you'll end up downloading encrypted versions of every e-mail in the world to find yours.  You'd need an NSA-scale server to handle that.)

Comment: @HenryCohn: In that you are obviously right -- and this is also the main reason why I said that it is still quite a way to go to get to anything practical.

Answer (score 15):

Let's assume that the secret service can view all transmitted messages and how they are routed, but has no access to anyone's private computer, since otherwise privacy clearly cannot be guaranteed.

There's still no way to mathematically guarantee privacy in any realistic way.  One big problem is traffic analysis: the secret service can try to correlate when you send messages with when other people receive messages (this correlation needs to take place over time; an individual message is certainly not enough by itself, and this can only detect patterns of frequent communication, but that is already a problem).  This doesn't even require extensive access to the internals of the network, but just the ability to monitor when users send or receive anything.  Encryption will disguise the messages themselves, but not who is communicating.

Perhaps the most obvious way to try to foil traffic analysis is by introducing random delays into the system.  If the delays are long enough, then it can make traffic analysis much harder, but delays cause severe problems of their own.  (Real-time chat becomes impossible, and even e-mail becomes less useful as the delays grow.)  And even with delays, making traffic analysis harder and less useful is not the same as making it impossible.

The only guaranteed way to defeat traffic analysis is to communicate all the time.  If there's ever a period in which you do not send any messages, then the secret service will know that any messages received during that time either were sent before you stopped communicating or weren't from you.  That's already a small information leak.  Of course it might not matter in practice, but this is important if we want a mathematical guarantee.  It is difficult to model what someone might guess in practice from small leaks, especially when combined with side information, so at a rigorous level all bets are off once information starts to leak.

So this means that if a group of people want to defeat traffic analysis rigorously, then they must all be communicating nonstop, using dummy messages if they don't have anything real to say.  This is not generally considered realistic, and I don't know of any large-scale implementation.

Of course nonstop communication is not enough by itself: you also need a system for routing messages indirectly.  If nonstop communication isn't an obstacle, then you can guarantee privacy using [mix networks](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/358549.358563), in which a sequence of trusted servers anonymize and randomly permute messages.  If all the servers are compromised, then the system becomes insecure, but otherwise it's OK.

In practice, people see constant communication as too costly for whatever benefit it offers.  However, mix networks are a good idea nevertheless.  The most widespread implementation is [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29).  Tor does not provide mathematically guaranteed privacy, and it can be vulnerable to traffic analysis.  However, it still provides far more anonymity than the internet does by default.

Of course then there are all sorts of meta-questions.  For example, Tor is not very common among internet users.  Does it actually attract attention and signal that Tor users are interesting targets for more careful investigation?  I've got no idea.

Mathematics certainly plays an important role in addressing privacy concerns, and there's more it could contribute than it currently does.  However, the practical constraints are significant, and privacy issues ultimately transcend any specific mathematical model.  Sadly, there's no realistic scenario in which internet users could say "Do what you like, because mathematics guarantees our privacy."

Comment: I think at any given time there are so many internet users sending or receiving something that it seems hardly possible to tell much alone from who communicates when. Occasional dummy information which goes to nobody or comes from nobody may be used in addition. Maybe I'm mistaken, but so far what you say does not convince me. I'm sorry to say it in that way -- but what you write is not a mathematical analysis of the problem, but just an essay.

Comment: @StefanKohl: You're certainly right that a single instance is almost useless, because the internet is large enough that it could fit any number of possibilities.  However, patterns emerge over time: if someone observes that 10% of the time Alice sends a message, Bob quickly receives one, then they can be confident that Alice communicates frequently with Bob and they can make pretty accurate guesses about which messages were to him.  Most people don't send so many messages, so this sort of timing-based traffic analysis is completely feasible if you have the timing data.  I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry, but still I don't see any kind of mathematical argumentation. -- My question was not for opinions.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're looking for an argument that timing-based traffic analysis is a genuine concern, or that it's difficult to defend against.  If you want a system in which traffic analysis is provably impossible, then you must disguise when you are transmitting and receiving.  If you assume this can be monitored, then the only way to fully disguise it is to communicate constantly.  This doesn't rule out the possibility of making a system that defeats traffic analysis in practice, but it says you won't be able to eliminate all possible information leaks.

Comment: Of course you might not care whether a little information leaks, as long as it seems harmless.  But then you are making assumptions beyond what can be proved.  You could try to model the leaking information somehow and show that it's harmless in your model, but this is a notoriously messy area.  Communication systems can be used in all sorts of ways, and the availability of unanticipated side information can dramatically change what's worrisome.  It seems nearly impossible to model this sort of thing in a broadly convincing way.

Comment: So I'd summarize it as follows.  In the standard model, where you want to prove that no information can possibly leak, you can solve the problem but only unrealistically.  You might be able to solve the problem in practice, but without proofs.  You might be able to prove that there are no leaks of a particular sort you find worrisome, but then you give up the universal applicability of the standard model.

Comment: Traffic analysis can take more into account than just the source and destination IP or MAC addresses (or their analogues). Network infrastructure and protocols are not designed to (or capable of) obscuring other very relevant information. I cannot resist citing http://eqnets.com/Images/overview.pdf

Comment: A more realistic model might have one "safe" central computer that is constantly sending out bits to all others, and in fact is the only source of outwards info. Then the other computers can send in bits into the safe computer whenever they want and it will redirect the information to the appropriate destination. Because computers only receive information (mostly useless) from the central computer, there is no way to track who is communicating to whom.

Comment: (In other words, I don't think it's true that ALL computers in the network must be communicating nonstop to rigorously defeat network analysis, if there is one computer everyone can trust and which the adversary government cannot look inside.)

Comment: @HenryCohn: the amount of data transmitted over the Internet is so huge that there is no need for random delays. There are enough packets transmitted every millisecond to make send/receive correlation analysis completely useless. The way secret service detect communication between Alice and Bob is by analysing IP packets that must tell the destination IP address: otherwise routers would have no way of knowing where to deliver it. And this is unavoidable: if you don't include the address the message won't reach the destination.

Comment: @SamHopkins: It's a good point that sending times alone are useless by themselves, but they can be very valuable given some side information. Suppose Alice is receiving data from a confidential informant, and even she doesn't know who it is. If someone hacks her account to learn when she received the relevant messages, and they have large scale data for what was sent when, they could learn something (if she has communicated often enough with the informant).

Comment: @HenryCohn: Could you say something more quantitative on time-based traffic analysis? -- Probably many things can be done if times both are known and coincide, say, up to nano- or picosecond. But in practice precision of coincidences will be MUCH lower, given that already the light takes as much as 1 millisecond to travel 300 kilometers, and added artificial imprecision in this order of magnitude won't harm. If time-based traffic analysis is anyway a big concern, now in times of internet flatrates it would even not be unrealistic to make all computers communicate always when they are online.

Comment: Here's a crude toy model (not trying to be realistic).  Suppose Alice and Bob run their own mail servers.  All their mail is encrypted and routed through anonymous remailers, so the only available information is timing for sent and received e-mails, but let's suppose the secret service gets this timing information from Alice and Bob's internet service providers (maybe willingly, maybe through hacking routers).  Suppose they each send 50 e-mails per day and receive 1000, including spam.

Comment: Let's imagine the e-mails are uniformly distributed throughout the day, and let's quantize things down to the minute level to account for imprecision and delivery time.  Since there are 1440 minutes per day, there's about a 50% chance of receiving an e-mail in any given minute.  (More precisely, $1-(1-1/1440)^{1000}$, or 50.07%.)  So if Alice and Bob are not e-mailing each other, about 50% of Alice's sent e-mails should randomly correspond to a received e-mail by Bob during the same minute.  If 10% of Alice's e-mail's are intended for Bob, then 55% of them correspond ($0.1+0.9\cdot0.5$).

Comment: Now suppose the secret service is monitoring a billion pairs of people like this, some of whom are corresponding 10% of the time and some of whom aren't corresponding, and the monitoring lasts for a year.  That's a long time, but the secret service is patient in building up their databases.  Suppose they classify all of the billion pairs into two groups, based on whether the observed probability is greater than 52.5%, and interpret this as whether the pair is communicating.  If I've calculated right, then the probability that they misclassify even one of the billion pairs is less than 1%.

Comment: I'm certainly not claiming this calculation in any way reflects the real world, but it shows that you can detect patterns even given a fair amount of imprecision and noise.

Comment: @HenryCohn: Thanks. -- If your thoughts are somehow realistic, I think this suggests the need to produce a lot of mock patterns, i.e. for example to make some groups of computers engage in heavy dummy communication with each other in times which are not needed for "real" communication.

Answer (score 4):

Unconditional sender privacy is a well-known problem;
[D. Chaum - "The dining cryptographers problem"](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~nemo/anonymity/papers/chaum-dc.pdf)
could be a reasonable starting point.

Having decided on existance, the question remains what price (in terms of communication complexity) could be considered acceptable to name it efficient enough (that is, practical).

"Dining" communication scheme had a impact and was extended in a number of ways, including an option for lost messages:
[M. Waidner, B. Pfitzmann - The dining cryptographers in the disco: Unconditional sender and recipient untraceability with computationally secure serviceability](http://freehaven.net/anonbib/cache/disco.ps.gz).

For a practical (depending on a computationally hard problem) solution, ["remailer"](http://www.cypherpunks.to/remailers/) was designed long ago for email.
Papers of Lance Cotrell and Ulf Moeller there could be of interest.
This was mentioned by Henry Cohn as "mix network" already.

Answer (score 3):

Think of the handwritten letters for a moment. Suppose Alice wants to secretly communicate with Bob, so she writes the message in a secret language that only Alice and Bob know, puts it in an envelope, and ... writes Bob's address in plain letters on the top of the envelope before mailing it. Big Brother may not be able to read the message, but surely can read the address on the envelope: if Alice would try to encrypt Bob's address she would completely confuse the Post Office and the letter won't get delivered.

It's pretty much the same thing with Internet communications. Cryptography obscures the message, but not the destination: otherwise the routers won't be able to deliver the message. This leads to the negative answer under the assumption that Big Brother watches **all** the nodes.

However, Big Brother does not have access to **all** the nodes: quite a few of them are overseas. Therefore Alice can try to secretly communicate with Bob by bouncing her messages off offshore nodes.

Back to our handwritten letter analogy. Alice can put her letter addressed to Bob into another envelope addressed to her Russian friend Ivan and write Ivan's address on the exterior envelope. Ivan receives the letter, takes it out of the exterior envelope, and hands it letter to his friend Alexander. Alexander then forwards Bob the original letter. Assuming that Big Brother has no ears in Moscow and that Internet traffic is heavy enough between Moscow and whichever country Big Brother is watching over, it would be virtually impossible for Big Brother to detect Alice-Bob communications. There are too many letters coming back-and-forth between the countries to guess that the letter Bob receives from Alexander is the same one that Alice sent to Ivan.

This is pretty much how hackers try to conceal their identities, in my layman understanding. This is not always successful though: Big Brother may have ears in Moscow as well...

Comment: Shouldn't your Muscovites be called Cyril and Dimitry?

Comment: Your model with addressed single data packages travelling through the network from a sender to a recipient is just the most obvious possibility, and what is actually used in the internet. -- Other protocols are conceivable -- though, if feasible, admittedly conceptually more difficult.

Comment: Imagine e.g. a protocol where, when A sends a message to B, A encodes the message and *merges* (think of a mathematical process, not just kind of concatenation!) it with a *big* pool of other data with other sources and destinations, in such a way that some mathematical process ensures that the nodes transport it to B *without knowing* that they are doing so, and in such way that the way the message takes cannot be traced within all the lots of other data it is merged into. I don't know whether this is feasible or not -- but problems like this are what I think a good answer should address.

Comment: @StefanKohl: the nodes need to know that they are transmitting something to B. They may not be aware of the primary origin of the message, only the immediate origin needs to be known. As described in my answer, the primary origin could be hidden by bouncing off offshore nodes; as you described in the comment the primary origin can be hidden in the pool of other messages. As long as there is an intermediate node - either overseas or in your _big pool_ server - you can mask true origin A. Until, that is, Big Brother makes a deal with Moscow or issues a warrant for you _big pool_ server.

Comment: Why do the nodes need to know that they are transmitting something to B? -- I think it is at least conceivable that this information is encoded by A into the data in some way such that, although the nodes cannot decipher the destination address or track the data within all the other data in the network, some mathematical process ensures that the data is shipped to B. I don't know whether this is feasible, but simply claiming that it is not is not a good answer.

Comment: "secret service can view all transmitted messages and how they are routed, but has no access to anyone's private computer, since otherwise privacy clearly cannot be guaranteed." In this case everything depends on what the people are allowed to put in their computers before the government starts watching.

Comment: @StefanKohl: what you describe is possible (using UDP/IP protocol instead of TCP/IP), but infeasible: every Alice would have to specify too many fake recipients to hide her Bob and the entire IP infrastructure would screech to a halt.

Comment: With all due respect, the scheme described looks like Chaum' mix-net mentioned already (and studied in details). Regarding timing: remailers collect incoming e-mail messages, process and send out the whole bunch on regular intervals. Each step makes it harder (larger number of cases) to correlate input-output based on timing.

Comment: [D. Chaum - Untraceable Electronic Mail, Return Addresses, and Digital Pseudonyms; 1981](http://freehaven.net/anonbib/cache/chaum-mix.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

If Alice encrypts a a lot of messages with Bob's RSA public key, after a while they can be identified as being directed to Bob, since the encrypted value is a number from the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$ where $N$ is Bob's RSA modulus.  By collecting enough of these ciphertexts, Big Brother can notice that they max out around $N$.  That is enough to distinguish them from messages addressed to Charlie, who has a different modulus.

There is an old rectangularization trick to get around this (I'm not sure who invented it).  Remember that Alice's message to Bob is $C=x^e\mod N$ where $e$ is a public encryption exponent.  So Alice simply generates a large random number $R$ (say in the range $1\dots 2^{100}$) and sends $C+RN$ instead of just $C$.  This is pretty close to uniformly random in the range of the maximum R.  Bob simply mods out by $N$ to get rid of the random addition, before decrypting.

This scheme actually does leak a little bit of information, according to an old paper by Quisqater that I don't remember the title of.  But IIRC it is pretty good for practical usage if the number of messages is reasonable.